# How to fix the emplacement of the picture in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nsurl, image

I'm playing with the tabbar, navigationBar and SegmentedBar in my application.

I have to show an picture from a HTTP like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // build the URL, perform the request and show the picture
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.clementhallet.be/15avril.png"];

    //UIImage
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];
}
```

It's running but the picture isn't where I want [exactly][1].

Thanks to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the right order:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); 

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

---

You've got to set the frame of your imageview for positioning. If not in interface builder done, do it like this:

```
image.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 
 image.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
        [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];


->Request for member 'frame' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Ah I see, embed your image in a UIImageView (`[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];`) or add it to a UIView, else you won't be able to set the frame.

Comment: `//UIImage 
 [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
 
 image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 
 
 image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
 
 //image.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);
 
 [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];`

give me the same issue...

Comment: I've added an example in my answer. Please add source to your question and format it, so much is not reabable in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I've updates the first post
I've made that but it doesn't work. DO I have to do an outlet??? FOr the moment thee is a simple View (before I had one ImageView but i just deleted it)

Comment: Please look at the order of creation: image has to exist before you create the imageView. Also in my example.

Comment: finally, I use your code (hunderd of thanks) but I've put CGRectMake(0, 65, image.size.width, image.size.height); to have the right size ;-)

Comment: very good, yes it was just an example rect, I could not guess what will position it correctly :)

Comment: I know, it was to feed a bit the question ;-). Nick, you're my saviour ;-)